# Dotless fails silently when parsing Bootstrap 2.3.1 to CSS

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, less, dotless

Here's my LessTransform class I use to parse `.less` files into `.css` files:

```
public class LessTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
        response.ContentType = "text/css";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to parse the downloaded `bootstrap.css` file using my `LessTransform` class. When the method is running, initially `response.Content` has the contents of Bootstrap.

After the call to `dotless.Core.Less.Parse()`, `response.Content` is blank. The parser is failing silently.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LESS parsing doesn't have any error handling, so all errors are being silently ignored. If you were handling errors, you'd see the following:

```
Expected '}' on line 577 in file '../bootstrap/mixins.less':
[576]: 
[577]:     .spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
       --------------------^
[578]:       .span@{index} { .span(@index); }
```

It looks like Bootstrap uses some LESS syntax that DotLESS does not yet support. You could try an older Bootstrap version (I've used Bootstrap 2.0 with DotLESS before).

To implement error handling, you need to add an `ILogger` implementation. Something like this:

```
var config = new DotlessConfiguration
{
    LogLevel = LogLevel.Error,
    // Put your custom logger implementation here
    Logger = typeof(LessCssLogger)
};

var lessEngine = new EngineFactory(config).GetEngine();
var outputCss = lessEngine.TransformToCss(response.Content, null);
Response.Content = outputCss;
```

Where `LessCssLogger` implements `ILogger`. DotLESS comes with a `AspResponseLogger` that you might be able to use.

Comment: Where can I find older version of Bootstrap? Their `tags` in the Github repo download the source files and I don't want to compile the thing myself. Would rather just download a single file.

Comment: I **removed** all instances of `\9` in the bootstrap.css file that comes with the official download and Dotless is now parsing things correctly.

Anybody have any idea what exactly `\9` is and if it's not intended to be there? Either way, removing `\9` fixes the problem.

Comment: The \9 is a hack for IE apparently, so if you remove it you will reduce the compatibility with certain versions of IE. Here are a couple of references I found to it:
http://webdood.com/?p=57
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Comment: A follow on to this comment - rather than just removing all \9 in bootstrap.css, I changed each to e("\9") and then dotLess was able to process the files successfully. I tested things by browsing directly to my css files to make sure I was getting valid css back - i.e. http://locahost/app/content/css/style.less.css